# How to setup indent size when continuing expression on new line in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, line-breaks

Let's say we have following code (Java):

```
repository.add(priceStream);
```

But for some reason I'd like to make it in following way:

> ```
> repository.add(
>         priceStream);
> ```

- it has 8 spaces in the line beginning. When I place caret between "(" and "p" and press "Enter" IDEA makes 4 space-indent by default. How could I setup it?

Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using in your example? Java?

Comment: yep, Java (question is fixed)

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Comment: yeah, I did, but it didn't work. Trying to understand how Continuation indent works as when I'm setting it to 12 I don't see any change :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the value to **8** of **`Continuation indent`** in the following path:

```
Settings > Editor > Code Style > File type (Ex. Java) > Tabs and indents (first tab)
```

Comment: after disabling EditorConfig support it worked, thanks!